# jQuery determine if any inputs within a div is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

How do you determine if any input within div1 is focused with jQuery?

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <div id="div2">
        <input type="text" id="input2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Teemu I believe the OP is referring to focused text inputs.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes, focused*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($("#div1 input:focus").length > 0){
   alert('An input is selected');
}else{
   alert('No inputs selected.');
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6r8RQ/

Docs: [`:focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/), [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

Answer (score 0):

Short and to the point:

```
if ( $("#div1").find("input:focus")[0] ) {...}
```

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements. The .find() and .children() methods are similar,
>   except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/find/

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMfz8/1/)**